# C# & ASM - Jump to Address

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64

I am writing a code Injection using C# to analyze potential malware software.

For that I jump to unallocated memory, write to that unallocated memory and jump back / return.
The code injection / allocation part works great without issues but the Jump part is difficult.

I took sample code for a 32bit process, but mine is 64bit so I converted it to 64bit and I might broke something while doing that as the Jump Address is not the right one where it should jump to.

As Example I want to do a code Injection at Address: 7FF95BBD0000.

My code looks like that:

```
public void injection()
{
    _oMemory.Alloc(out _newmem, 0x300); //Allocate 300 Bytes of unallocated Memory for the code Injection (This part works)

    var CodeBaseAddress = ModuleBaseAddress + 0x36652EE; //I want to jump from this Address (7FFBA13F52EE output = 140718718800622) to (7FF95BBD0000)
    var CodeInjectionAddress = (ulong)_newmem; //This is the Address of the Code Injection that I want to jump to (7FF95BBD0000 output = 140708962697216)

    var Jumpbytes = Jmp(ConeInjectionAddress, CodeBaseAddress, false); //this should give me the byte[] Byte Decimal for the Jump from the CodeBaseAddress to the CodeInjectionAddress but it gives me a slightly wrong output (outputs = {233, 13, 173, 192, 94, 4, 128, 255, 255}, in Hex = {0xE9, 0x0D, 0xAD, 0x7D, 0xBA, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF}, in OPCode = "jmp 7FFB5BBD0000")

    _oMemory.Write((IntPtr)ad1, bv1); //This writes the Jumpbytes to the CodeBaseAddress which works

    _oMemory.CloseHandle(); //Closes Handle which also works
}

public static byte[] Jmp(ulong jmpto, ulong jmpfrom, bool nop)
{
    var test = jmpto - jmpfrom;
    var test2 = test - 5;
    var dump = test2.ToString("x"); //Get original bytes

    if (dump.Length == 7) //Make sure we have 4 bytes
        dump = "0" + dump;

    dump += "E9"; //Add JMP
        if (nop)
            dump = "90" + dump; //Add NOP if needed

    var hex = new byte[dump.Length / 2];
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
        hex[i] = Convert.ToByte(dump.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16); //Set each byte to 2 chars

    Array.Reverse(hex); //Reverse byte array for use with Write()

    return hex;

}
```

Notice how the Jmp method returns "7FFB5BBD0000" instead of "7FF95BBD0000". It changes the 95 to a B5 which leads to a wrong Jump Address.

Also another weird thing is that the jump to the wrong address looks like this:
[image]

And if I would change the jump to my desired Address using cheat engine it looks like this:
[image]

I guess my Jump is too "big" using the E9 jump so it gives me a wrong Jump address with my Method? How could I fix that?

Thanks for anyone helping me out or pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: The second solution is an absolute indirect jump through an embedded pointer. It's doing `jmp [rip+0]; dq 7FF95BBD0000`

Comment: `ff 25 00 00 00 00` is `jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]`, reading the following 8 bytes as data.  Those aren't part of the instruction, they could be placed anywhere in memory.  More normally you'd `mov reg, imm64` and `jmp reg` to reach an address more than +-2GiB away from the current location.

Comment: Your relative offset being wrong hints at `ProcessBaseAddress` being wrong. Maybe you wanted `ModuleBaseAddress` or similar.

Comment: @Jester no the ProcessBaseAddress is correct which is the ModuleBaseAddress of the UserAssembly.dll which I need. Just named it that way to make it look "simpler". But thanks for pointing that out will change the example to prevent confusion.

Comment: @PeterCordes okay I understand. How would I calculate the jump to the desired address using the mov reg, im64 / jmp reg or jmp QWORD...?

Comment: Those are absolute there is no need to calculate anything just stick the bytes into the instruction.